# Kendo Grid dynamic header population with angular 7

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular7

Am developing a kendo grid with column header to be dynamic from a api response data , i could find lots of idea when using jquery, is there anyway to load the columns data from angular component class to template html.any links would do.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is setting the header template. You can read about it [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/HeaderTemplateDirective/).

Basically, you do the following:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName">
        <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
              {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Inside the template you can use whatever members you have on the component.

**Note:** If the data you're using in the template is updated in an asynchronous call and you're using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, you need to add `changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef` to your constructor parameters and let the change detector know that it has to check for changes using `this.changeDetector.markForCheck()`.

**See a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bnt66)**.

Comment: hi thanks for the response am able to bound the field row wise where as am looking for somethng where i fill the header with column field data .. for eg .. column.field data has to be bound in the header instead of ProductName i should be able to bind Chai and in next column i bind the next productname dynamically , this i can do using jquery like so http://dojo.telerik.com/IWaCozAl any link for angular 7

Comment: I've added a demo. I think it answers your question. If it doesn't, please try explaining it in another way.

Comment: Thanks for the sample am looking for where i could pass the data for eg Chai in a column1 as title and next column2 title holds Chang like so passing the data response as column title , more eg- i have a data where i have to do like ShopName - column1 title will be the products they sell and the price loaded as column1 field data. like shop1 sells chai for 20 and Shop1 sells chang for 25. Thanks for the response.

Comment: will this support save operation for the grid ?